# JavaScript - Filter object based on multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to filter some data based on multiple values. `Language`, `title` and `slug`

```
[
{
    de: "4567uy55",
    en: "654321",
    lang: [
      {
        id: "654321",
        language: "English",
        title: "Title1"
      },
      {
        id: "4567uy55",
        language: "German",
        title: "Title2"
      }
    ],
    slug: 'some-slug'
},
...
]
```

What I have now returns all objects which have one or part of the filters(in case title is `This is a title`, the word `this` should match), but I need to return objects which have all of them. 
I used an object flattner just to get all properties and values in one object, but I can't get it to filter the way I need it.

```
multiFilter = (arr, filters) => {

console.log(filters)
console.log(arr)

let newArray = []

for (let c of arr) {

    let flatCourse = flatten(c)

    for (let k in flatCourse) {

        const keyArr = k.split('/')
        const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters)

        Object.keys(filters).map((key) => {

            if (keyArr.includes(key)) {

                const flatVal = flatCourse[k].toString().toLowerCase()
                const filterVal = filters[key].toString().toLowerCase()

                console.log(flatVal)
                console.log(filterVal)

                if (flatVal.includes(filterVal)) {
                    arr = []
                    arr.push(c)
                    newArray.push(c)
                }

            }
        })
    }

}

return newArray


}
```

Filters look like this:

```
[

language:["English"],
title: ["Some title"],
slug:["some slug"]

]
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example of an input and your desired output?

Comment: Input is the array of objects I defined in my question and output is any object which matches the filters pushed in `newArray`. So `newArray` should contain objects which match all the filters.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to filter by `language/lang` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mixing for loops and functional chaining you could just go with one of them:

```
 multiFilter = (arr, filters) => 
   arr.map(flatten).filter(el => // filter out elements from arr
     Object.entries(filters).every(([fKey, fValues]) => // ensure that every key is included in the object
       Object.entries(el).some(([oKey, oValue]) => 
          oKey.split("/").includes(fKey) && fValues.includes(oValue)// make sure that at least one of the values equals the elements value
       )
     )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.filter(course => {
    // Returns an array of booleans corresponding to whether or not each filter condition is satisfied
    return Object.keys(filters).map(key => {
        return filters[key].map(filter => {
            // Special case here because lang is an array
            if (key == 'language' && course.lang != undefined) {
                return course.lang.some(lang => lang[key].includes(filter))
            }

            if (course[key] == undefined) {
                return false
            }

            return course[key].includes(filter)
        }).every(result => result == true)
    }).every(result => result == true)
})
```