# How do I filter an object based on multiple nested criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got the following object and I'm trying to filter and return players from both groups based on multiple criteria such as "show me all players where franchise = Marvel, and power= flight" but I'm getting hung up in multiple levels of filtering.

I was looking at this answer but it doesn't seem to fit my scenario: [JavaScript - Filter object based on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604255/javascript-filter-object-based-on-multiple-values)

I can get results if I iterate over the groups but there are potentially lots of groups and I didn't want to get hung up in that. Is that the best way, though?

```
oPlayers.players.groups.filter(function(hero){return hero.Id == 1})
```

```
oPlayers = {
    "players": {
        "groups": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "hero": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1,
                        "name": "Batman",
                        "franchise": "DC", 
                        "gender": "Male", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"stealth"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"weaponry"}]
                    },                  
                    {
                        "Id": 2,
                        "name": "Ironman",
                        "franchise": "Marvel", 
                        "gender": "Male", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"weaponry"}]
                    },          
                    {
                        "Id": 3,
                        "name": "Supergirl",
                        "franchise": "DC", 
                        "gender": "Female", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"strength"},{"power":"speed"}]
                    },                  
                    {
                        "Id": 4,
                        "name": "Valkyrie",
                        "franchise": "Marvel", 
                        "gender": "Female", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"strength"}]
                    }           
                ]
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "hero": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1,
                        "name": "Batwoman",
                        "franchise": "DC", 
                        "gender": "Female", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"stealth"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"weaponry"}]
                    },                  
                    {
                        "Id": 2,
                        "name": "IronPepper",
                        "franchise": "Marvel", 
                        "gender": "Female", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"weaponry"}]
                    },              
                    {
                        "Id": 3,
                        "name": "Superman",
                        "franchise": "DC", 
                        "gender": "Male", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"strength"},{"power":"speed"}]
                    },                  
                    {
                        "Id": 4,
                        "name": "Thor",
                        "franchise": "Marvel", 
                        "gender": "Male", 
                        "powers": [{"power":"flight"},{"power":"intelligence"},{"power":"strength"}]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding boolean logic? Use only one filter and have a bunch of if statements. Alternatively, chain filters together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get a single list of all players. Then, given that your criteria is specified as an object, you can filter players based on whether `every` property specified in `criteria` matches properties of a player:

```js
function filter(players, criteria) {
  return players.players.groups.flatMap(({Id, hero}) => 
    hero.filter(p =>
      Object.entries(criteria).every(([k, v]) => {
        if (k === 'power') return p.powers.some(({power}) => power === v);
        return p[k] === v;
      }))
      .map(p => ({groupId: Id, ...p})));
}

const oPlayers = {
  "players": {
    "groups": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "hero": [{
            "Id": 1,
            "name": "Batman",
            "franchise": "DC",
            "gender": "Male",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "stealth"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "weaponry"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "name": "Ironman",
            "franchise": "Marvel",
            "gender": "Male",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "weaponry"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "name": "Supergirl",
            "franchise": "DC",
            "gender": "Female",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "strength"
            }, {
              "power": "speed"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "name": "Valkyrie",
            "franchise": "Marvel",
            "gender": "Female",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "strength"
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "hero": [{
            "Id": 1,
            "name": "Batwoman",
            "franchise": "DC",
            "gender": "Female",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "stealth"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "weaponry"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "name": "IronPepper",
            "franchise": "Marvel",
            "gender": "Female",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "weaponry"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "name": "Superman",
            "franchise": "DC",
            "gender": "Male",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "strength"
            }, {
              "power": "speed"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "name": "Thor",
            "franchise": "Marvel",
            "gender": "Male",
            "powers": [{
              "power": "flight"
            }, {
              "power": "intelligence"
            }, {
              "power": "strength"
            }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(filter(oPlayers, {gender: 'Male', franchise: 'Marvel'}));
console.log(filter(oPlayers, {gender: 'Female', power: 'flight'}));
```

Comment: How would I rework this so I could keep the group Id value? I forgot to include that in my original post.

Comment: @ChrisG. you'd have to use 2 loops, so you can `flatMap` in the function itself. This way, you'd know the group id when building the final result (see updated answer).

Comment: Thought I might. Also, just found out, I need to filter on a passed value for powers as well. i.e. gender: 'Male', franchise: 'Marvel', powers: 'flight'

Comment: @ChrisG. the above function filters by power (as of now, the key in the `criteria` object is expected to be called `power`, but you can modify the code so that it is `powers`)